# Adding custom css to a theme depending on whether the admin user is logged in or not

Tags: css, admin-css

Is it possible to add custom css to a stylesheet in a theme depending on whether the user is logged in or not?

When I log in, the theme navigation and when viewing the main site bar is hidden behind the wpadminbar and I would like to change the css of the theme nav bar only when an admin is logged in and when the site is being viewed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your main site bar is being blocked.

you could just add some custom CSS to the

```
#wpadminbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: -xx px;
}
```

Where xx px moves the bar enough to see what you need to see.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a user is an admin, use `( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )`.

Then you can enqueue your css file that changes the nav position accordingly in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ic_admin_navbar_frontend_css' );
function ic_admin_navbar_frontend_css() {
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && ! is_admin() ) { // we don't want to load this on the admin side, just the front end
        wp_enqueue_style( 'ic-navbar-fix', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/pathtofile/in/templatedirectory/my_special.css' );
    } // end check for admin user on frontend
} // end ic_navbar function
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Sorry, I misread the question... To check whether someone is logged in, admin or not, you can use `is_user_logged_in()`. Just replace `current_user_can()` above and you should be good to go.